# Get bpy.data of all DriverTarget.id_type

Tags: python, scripting

##### I need to get all `bpy_prop_collection` of `DriverTarget.id_type`, but miss 2 of them.

```
# get all id_type
# enum_items = bpy.types.DriverTarget.bl_rna.properties["id_type"].enum_items

dic = {
    "ACTION":           bpy.data.actions,
    "ARMATURE":         bpy.data.armatures,
    "BRUSH":            bpy.data.brushes,
    "CAMERA":           bpy.data.cameras,
    "CACHEFILE":        bpy.data.cache_files,
    "CURVE":            bpy.data.curves,
    "FONT":             bpy.data.fonts,
    "GREASEPENCIL":     bpy.data.grease_pencils,
    "COLLECTION":       bpy.data.collections,
    "IMAGE":            bpy.data.images,
    "KEY":              bpy.data.shape_keys,
    "LIGHT":            bpy.data.lights,
    "LIBRARY":          bpy.data.libraries,
    "LINESTYLE":        bpy.data.linestyles,
    "LATTICE":          bpy.data.lattices,
    "MASK":             bpy.data.masks,
    "MATERIAL":         bpy.data.materials,
    "META":             bpy.data.metaballs,
    "MESH":             bpy.data.meshes,
    "MOVIECLIP":        bpy.data.movieclips,
    "NODETREE":         bpy.data.node_groups,
    "OBJECT":           bpy.data.objects,
    "PAINTCURVE":       bpy.data.paint_curves,
    "PALETTE":          bpy.data.palettes,
    "PARTICLE":         bpy.data.particles,
    "LIGHT_PROBE":      bpy.data.lightprobes,
    "SCENE":            bpy.data.scenes,
    "SIMULATION":       ???,
    "SOUND":            bpy.data.sounds,
    "SPEAKER":          bpy.data.speakers,
    "TEXT":             bpy.data.texts,
    "TEXTURE":          bpy.data.textures,
    "CURVES":           ???,
    "POINTCLOUD":       bpy.data.pointclouds,
    "VOLUME":           bpy.data.volumes,
    "WINDOWMANAGER":    bpy.data.window_managers,
    "WORLD":            bpy.data.worlds,
    "WORKSPACE":        bpy.data.workspaces,
}
```

Comment: how will you use these properties if you don't mind me asking? I checked in driver properties and `id_type` *SIMULATION* (physics) and *CURVES* (hair) seem not to be supported as driver as blender disables the `ID-Block` field when those types are selected.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. I use it to loop all of them and get the keys, for example: `if id_type == 'MESH':  for k in bpy.data.meshes.keys(): print(k)`

Comment: `CURVES` is now supported in version 3.4 with `bpy.data.curves`. `SIMULATION` not yet.